# Where does this rocket app icon come from?

Tags: android, flutter, android-icons

My flutter app has this weird rocket icon that I've never seen before.
[image: Mysterious rocket app icon]
All other apps start out with the default blue flutter icon, but not this one.
My guess is, that it has something to do with the fact that it is a launcher app.

How can I get rid of that icon overwriting my own icon?

I've already placed my own icon through the `flutter_launcher_icons` package and double checked that it's in the android manifest at

```
<application
            android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
            ...
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

and that the correct icons are in the `res/mipmap`-Folders

Answer (score 0):

Have you entered this?

```
 $ flutter pub pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

And did you add the dependency to the pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: That's what I did - and it works for my other apps, just not for my current one. :(

Comment: Try migrating your files to a new project. that's a little bit frustrating but worth trying.

Comment: yeah, I had this in mind too - thx, I will let you know the outcome!